# NumPy: indexing one element from a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following 8 by 8 array named `arr`:

```
[[False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False]]
```

I want to set specific elements of it to `True`, for which I have this `filtered_ind` array:

```
[[5 6]
 [4 5]
 [2 5]
 [1 6]]
```

Trying to do this:

```
arr[filtered_ind] = True
```

Results in the following:

```
[[False False False False False False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [False False False False False False False  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [False False False False False False False False]]
```

Basically, it takes every number in the `filtered_ind` array, and sets those rows to `True`, instead of setting the specific elements.

I figured out that the indexing does not work the way I think it does, since `print(arr[filtered_ind])` gives me this:

```
[[[False False False False False False False False]
  [False False False False False False False False]]

 [[False False False False False False False False]
  [False False False False False False False False]]

 [[False False False False False False False False]
  [False False False False False False False False]]

 [[False False False False False False False False]
  [False False False False False False False False]]]
```

instead of what I expect, which would be `[False False False False]` of course.

How do I fix this, and more importantly, why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only indexing along the first axis. You need:

```
a = np.full((8,8), False)
ix = np.array([[5, 6],[4, 5],[2, 5],[1, 6]])

a[ix[:,0], ix[:,1]] = True
```

Or we could also use [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) here:

```
np.add.at(a,tuple(zip(*ix)),True)

print(a)
[[False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False  True False]
 [False False False False False  True False False]
 [False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False  True False False]
 [False False False False False False  True False]
 [False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False]]
```

---

Keep in mind, that by indexing as you are, `a[ix]`, you are indexing *only* along the first axis. You'll see more clearly with a simpler example:

```
ix = np.array([[1,2],[0,3],[2,2]])

a = np.arange(0,16).reshape(4,4)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Now if you index along the first axis, as you were doing, you get:

```
a[ix]

array([[[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]])
```

Basically as many rows as values in the indices, with the shape of the indexing array. You must also specify *along which columns (second axis) you're indexing*, so as in the first approach, `[ix[:,0]` along the first axis and `ix[:,1]` along the second:

```
a[ix[:,0], ix[:,1]] = True
```

Comment: `tuple(zip(*ix))` can be `tuple(ix.T)`

Answer (score 0):

When indexing like you want to, you have to give a tuple of indices, not an array of indices. Like this:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9]])

ind = ([0,1],[1,2]) #this is a tuple of lists, not a list of lists
print(a[ind]) # [2,6]

a[ind] = 0 #Setting a[0,1] = 0 and a[1,2] = 0
print(a) 

a:
[[1 0 3]
 [4 5 0]
 [7 8 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`np.fromfunction`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html) together with [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(lambda i, j: [i,j] in filter_ind.tolist()), (8,8))
```